# Remove and replace whitespace with a character in a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string being returned and it has a space in between 2 words and I have no idea on how to replace the empty space with a character such as an underscore

I have tried using

```
Replace(" ", "_");
```

and

```
Replace(' ', '_');
```

but neither have worked.. an example of the string being returned is

> Hey There

and if the empty space is removed and replaced with an underscore it should look like this

> Hey_There

I am not overly familiar with Regex, I tried an example that someone else did but it didn't work

Any idea's?

Comment: How are you using it? Note that strings are immutable, which means you have to assign the result of the function to a (new) variable to use it.

Comment: Are you certain the 'Space' is an actual ASCII Space character?

Comment: You should post your actual code where you use this so we have some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in .NET. You need to assign result of `Replace` method to some variable to use it.

```
var myString = "Text with spaces";
myString = myString.Replace(' ', '_');
```

Comment: You answered first, when I can accept as answer then I will

Answer (score 2):

It might be just how you're using the function, e.g.

```
string myString = "Hey There";
myString.Replace(" ", "_");
```

This won't actually do anything because the Replace function is returning a string but you're not doing anything with it.

You might just need something like:

```
string myString = "Hey There";
myString = myString.Replace(" ", "_");
```

There to are updating the string to include your replacement.

Answer (score 1):

```
var hey = "Hey There";
hey = hey.Replace(' ', '_');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should have something like that:

```
s = s.Replace(" ", "_");
```

where s is the variable of the string.